# Can I bring an airsoft gun into the Phillipines?

Tags: international-travel, philippines, firearms

My question is if I would need a permit to transport an airsoft gun into the Philippines? Would I need to declare it.

I am not selling them or anything. I would be just keeping them for myself. Most of the laws I have read involve dealing or selling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Buying airsoft from HK and travelling back to country of origin via air](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89294/buying-airsoft-from-hk-and-travelling-back-to-country-of-origin-via-air)

Comment: Are you a tourist in the Philippines, or a citizen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not a citizen of PH, and you are genuine tourist, you cannot bring an air soft gun into the Philippines.

According to the ["Airsoft legal issues" Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_in_airsoft#Philippines) on the subject:

> "In the Philippines, you need to get a PTT (Permit To Transport)
> license and license the replica as a firearm with the government. It
> is also required thet the individual is joining a bonifide airsoft
> club and must be 18 years of age or older. You also need a license to
> manufacture/sale a airsoft replica. It is also mandated to have a
> Permit To Carry outside of residency license. Failure to comply with
> the rule is punishable by correctional imprisonment and a fine of Ten
> thousand Pesos (₱10,000).[45]"

Without the proper permitting and licensing, I would dare to say, you will not be able to legally import an airsoft gun into PH as a tourist.

Comment: I am a filipino citizen